# How to crash an Android Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am testing an Android crash reporting tool and would like to see how it responds to crashes coming from WebViews - i.e from the HTML/JavaScript/CSS code running in them.

My question is how to produce such a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the app side, you can do:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("chrome://crash");
```

Note that you can't do that from JS / HTML code directly -- the request for this URL must come from the browser side. But you can use Java Bridge to receive a command from the JS side:

```
class WebViewCrasher {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void crash() {
        // post a task to UI thread to load "chrome://crash"
     }
}
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewCrasher(), "crasher");
```

Then in your JS code you can call:

```
crasher.crash();
```

But make sure you are not injecting this object in the release version of your app :)

Comment: I added crasher.crash() to my JS code, but instead of a crash I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: crasher is not defined". The result was that the JS code stopped, but the WebView did not cause a crash.

Comment: Does your call to `addJavascriptInterface` stands before the call to `loadUrl` (or whatever method you use to load content into WebView)? See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: First webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "interOp"); then webView.loadUrl(myurl); After reading your answer more carefully, I see you are actually adding the crasher... I missed that before.

Comment: @Ahmedna You can't catch this kind of a crash in JavaScript or Java code. The crash happens in the native (C++) code and is handled by the operating system.